# Copy One Table from Another Database Won't Let Me Drop or Insert Into

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

There are many similar questions, but I have not found exactly what I am looking for.

I want to copy and completely update one table from one database to another. Then, each day, the SP will drop, and insert into the local database with the master database data. Or some other way to update the local copy.

Thinking of creating a stored procedure that does an "insert into" from the master database to the local database. When I did this, I get an error that the table already exists however.

Do I need to drop the entire table and then do the insert into? If so, can you post an example SQL please?

My problems:
1) When I try to drop the table and then do the insert into, I get the error that the the table does not exist in the context. It won't let me drop it.
2) When I do the insert into without the drop, it says the table already exists.
3) What is the best way to schedule the daily import?

```
USE Local_DB
CREATE PROCEDURE TransferProductTable;
DROP TABLE Local_DB.dbo.tbProduct
SELECT *
INTO Local_DB.dbo.tbProduct
FROM Master_DB.dbo.tbProduct
GO;
```

When I run this, I get the error that Local_DB.dbo.tbProduct already exists or when I add the drop table, I get that I cannot drop it because it does not exist.

I also read on here that SQL Management Studio has an Import Data task. Would it be better to created a scheduled task that ran that, or is that the same thing as creating scheduled task that runs a stored procedure?

This is running on a Windows box with MS SQL 2008.

Comment: SELECT INTO and INSERT INTO are two very different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking a lot of different questions. But the code your posted could be modified to work by using Truncate instead of DROP:

```
USE Local_DB 
CREATE PROCEDURE TransferProductTable; 
    Truncate Table Local_DB.dbo.tbProduct 
    Insert INTO Local_DB.dbo.tbProduct 
    select * FROM Master_DB.dbo.tbProduct 
GO;
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Do you think the scheduled task running the stored procedure is a good way to do this daily import?

Comment: I would create a SQL Server Agent Job to automate and track the daily execution of this procedure. Read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187061.aspx